# Unmarshal JSON to map[any]any

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshal a JSON object to a map of `map[any]any`. This yields the error `json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type map[interface {}]interface {}`. Why is this not possible?

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    bytes := []byte(`{"sendMsg":{"user":"ANisus","msg":"Trying to send a message"},"say":"Hello"}`)
    var bytesInMap map[any]any
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &bytesInMap)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello World %s", bytesInMap)
}
```

Comment: `map[any]any` isn't valid. maps can't have `any` types as keys. A map has to be `map[comparable]any`. Besides, you're handling a simple object, so either define a struct, but if nothing else, at the very least use `map[string]any`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Is there a way to cover all available `comparable` types?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: `map[any]any` is perfectly valid, but you of course can't insert a non-comparable key and json always uses `string` so decoding must use `map[string]any`

Comment: JSON keys are always `string`s. Use a `map[string]any`.

Comment: @JimB, then why does the code won't work? Could you please explain?

Comment: To be honest, considering you're having issues unmarshalling JSON into a map, I wouldn't  yet start looking to use stuff like this. `comparable` is part of go generics. Here, though, you know the data is coming in as an object. The only type that makes sense to use here is `map[string]any`... why bother with generics - it's JSON, the keys *will be strings*

Comment: `map[any]any`  is valid, but json unmarshaler won't work with it. JSON keys are always strings. They can be numeric strings, or boolean strings, but they are still strings.

Comment: @ErdemTuna, json uses `map[string]any`, see the [`json` package docs for `Unmarshal`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal)

Comment: Thank you all for the discussion and remarks. I got the idea.